# Missouri EOC and the best Geometry book

Tags: textbooks, geometry

I am a Missouri High School Geometry teacher.  WE are adopting textbooks this year.  I would like opinions on which books are most closely aligned with the Missouri Learning Standards because at the end of the year my students must take an EOC (End of Course Exam)

Comment: I removed the first line and believe this is not even an opinion-based question, so it should not be closed.  State standards are usually pretty specific and although the original post does not provide a link to them, presumably one could make quite concrete and evidence-based suggestions if one knew where to find them.